# DML not allowed on User

Tags: dml, update, upsert, insert

I created some test users using the following apex code which worked perfectly fine:

```
list<User> abc = new list<user>();
for(integer i=1; i<3;i++) {
    abc.add(
        new User(
            lastname = 'E' + i,
            Alias = 'E' + i,
            Email = 'validemail@gmail.com',
            Username = 'E' + i + '@EM' + i + '.com',
            CommunityNickname = 'E' + i,
            ProfileId = '00ej000000120yU',
            TimeZoneSidKey = 'GMT',
            LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
            EmailEncodingKey = 'ISO-8859-1',
            LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US'
        )
    );
}
insert abc;
```

After Inserting 3 records, I am trying to upsert  using the following code: ( I am getting the same error even if using this code for the first time i.e., even before inserting records)

```
list<User> abc = new list<user>();
for(integer i=1; i<11;i++) {
    abc.add(
        new User(
            lastname = 'E' + i,
            Alias = 'E' + i,
            Email = 'validemail@gmail.com',
            Username = 'E' + i + '@EM' + i + '.com',
            CommunityNickname = 'E' + i,
            ProfileId = '00ej000000120yU',
            TimeZoneSidKey = 'GMT',
            LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
            EmailEncodingKey = 'ISO-8859-1',
            LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
            Division = 'abdc'
        )
    );
}
upsert abc;
```

- "insert abc" is working perfectly if the record doesnot exist
- "update abc" on already inserted records throws the following error --- "MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call: []"
- "upsert abc" - no matter if the record already exists or updating or creating new, always errors out --- "DML not allowed on user"

Also, I am adding users to ChatterFree which has 400 count. So license, I believe is not a problem

Can someone please help me in understanding this issue. Thanks

Edit: Update issue resolved. I am getting that error because after inserting, I am trying to reuse the same code just by changing few fields(not all) and adding update to the bottom. But the following code works perfectly.

```
list<User> abc = [SELECT Username FROM User WHERE LastName = 'h1'];
for(User a : abc) {
    a.ProfileId = '00ej00000012hVk';
}
update abc;
```

Comment: can you please share the update code which is throwing the error?

Comment: in place of "insert abc" from the code I posted, I am using "update abc"

Comment: well, if you are using update instead of insert, it will obviously fail coz the records are not yet inserted. update will work only after insert or on a result which you have fetched using soql

Comment: I am using update after inserting the records, say if I try to update another field like  company = 'abc' and then update, even then getting the same error

Comment: please share that piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added the elements in the list and updating it without being inserted. I believe this is what you are trying to do:

```
list<User> abc = new list<user>();
for(integer i=1; i<3;i++) {
    abc.add(
        new User(
            lastname = 'E' + i,
            Alias = 'E' + i,
            Email = 'validemail@gmail.com',
            Username = 'E' + i + '@EM' + i + '.com',
            CommunityNickname = 'E' + i,
            ProfileId = '00ej000000120yU',
            TimeZoneSidKey = 'GMT',
            LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
            EmailEncodingKey = 'ISO-8859-1',
            LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US'
        )
    );
}
insert abc;

for(User userSo: abc){
abc.title='Hello';
}
update abc;
```

Comment: update issue resolved Rajiv. Can you throw some inputs on upsert which gives me error "DML not allowed on user"

Comment: please share the exact piece of code as it is which throws this error

Comment: updated with the actual "upsert" code I am using. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use the **Database.upsert** static method instead of the **upsert** DML keyword:

```
//failure (DML not allowed on User)
upsert user ExternalId__c;

//success
Database.upsert(new User(), User.ExternalId__c, true);
```